# How to take limited posts for every parents in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models with `has_many` relationship like

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :company
end
```

Now i'm trying to get results like this

**Abc** (Company contains > 100 posts)

- Infinity war
- The maze runner

**Xyz** (Company contains > 100 posts)

- Game of thrones
- The wire

So then concept is need to made a query for take only two child records for every company, not all.

I have tried like this

```
Post.order(id: :desc).group_by(&:company)
```

It has loaded all posts grouped by company then page is slower.

If I try like this

```
posts = Post.order(view_count: :desc).limit(20)
@posts = posts.group_by(&:company)
```

it's taking 20 posts but not for all companies.

I don't know is that enough for you to understand.

What can I do now.

Comment: What is **Abc** and **Xyz**?

Comment: It's ***companies*** I mean parents @andriy-baran

Comment: You want to have a list of companies which have post or post views greater than 100?

Comment: I want to get posts order by view_count desc for all companies, at first posts ordering then get group by companies

Comment: `Post.joins("INNER JOIN companies ON posts.company_id = companies.id ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 2 ")`

Comment: It's throw the error *ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "LIMIT": syntax error: SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN companies ON posts.company_id = companies.id ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 2 LIMIT ?* @seethrough

Comment: What is your desired result? Is it to show list of Companies with last X Posts from each Company?

Comment: I want to show two posts group_by company but posts order with view_count @Sharj

Comment: `Post.joins(:companies).order(view_count: :desc).group('companies.id').limit(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show like this:

```
Company A
- Post A 
- Post B

Company B
- Post C
- Post D
```

First get list of companies:

```
@companies = Company.all #You can add condition to take only those companies you want to show

@companies.each do |company|
  #print company name
  company.posts.order("view_count DESC").limit(2).each do |post|
    #print post.title
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! how to reverse company based on post view count, and that's the main issue.